# error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified while using distutils in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, setup.py, distutils

I am trying to call a C function from Python (Extending Python with C).

I built a hello.c file and a setup.py file. When I run the setup file it's supposed to build a Python extension so that I can import it in Python.

But, when I try to run `python setup.py install` I am getting the error

> error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

I tried setting up the environmental variable, `insert path in to sys`, but still the error persists.

Can someone identify where I'm going wrong?

setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

module1 = Extension('helloworld', sources = ['hello.c'])

setup(name='helloworld', version='1.0', ext_modules=[module1])
```

hello.c:

```
#include <Python.h>

static PyObject* helloworld(PyObject* self, PyObject* args) {
  return Py_BuildValue("s", "Hello, Python extensions!!");
}

static char helloworld_docs[] =
  "helloworld( ): Any message you want to put here!!\n";

static PyMethodDef helloworld_funcs[] = {
   {"helloworld", (PyCFunction)helloworld, 
      METH_NOARGS, helloworld_docs},
      {NULL}
};

void inithelloworld(void) {
   Py_InitModule3("helloworld", helloworld_funcs,
              "Extension module example!");
}
```

error:

[image: Screenshot of error]